# What's the deal with Vulcans and contractions?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

I was reading [this WikiHow article](http://www.wikihow.com/Live-Like-a-Vulcan) on how to become more Vulcan-like and the 7th step is

> When speaking, do not use contractions! Vulcans believe contractions in sentences are illogical.

I don't get it (I also have no idea where they are getting this from, though I'll take it on faith that it's not entirely made up).

Why would contractions be considered illogical? They convey the same meaning in a more parsimonious manner, saving time and energy. Isn't that logical?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Vulcans do use contractions

Neither [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan) (and [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_language)) nor [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Vulcan) make any reference to this 'rule' of not using contractions.

In fact, we know it's probably false:

- In *TOS* '[The Paradise Syndrome](http://The%20Paradise%20Syndrome)', Spock says the following:

  > SPOCK: There **isn't** time, Doctor. I must decipher those obelisk's symbols. They're a highly advanced form of cipher writing.
- In *ENT* 'Awakening', we have a couple of instances:

  > SOVAL; I could protest, but it wouldn't accomplish anything. V'Las **isn't** one to change his mind.

  and

  > T'LES: Syrrannites believe that Vulcans have strayed from the teachings of Surak. Considering what the High Command has done in recent years, the listening station at P'Jem, the suppression of dissent, our position **isn't** so hard to accept.
- In *ENT* 'Doctor's Orders', T'Pol says:

  > T'POL: **I'd** like to complete the diagnostic.

We have concrete evidence that Vulcans *do* use contractions.  It is fair to say that Vulcans don't *often* use contractions, but they occasionally do.

So, relax; you don't have to give up contractions!

Comment: I think the author of that article might be getting mixed up between Spock's more formal mode of speaking and Cmdr Data's lack of use of contractions

Comment: @Richard The latter is also not true. [Data uses contractions all the time](https://www.facebook.com/KyotoEnglish/videos/510389215727584/).

Comment: @mrlister - Yes, but he's not supposed to!